# How to debug an endless running variable?

Tags: c#

I tried to write an autoupdater for a program from me.
I already got rid of a stackOverflow and such but now my Program seems to run endless when he comes to a variable. And do nothing.

I tried to get info with cw and check where it is hanging but i get nothing and can not find it.

**My main**

```cs
    {
    updater = new Updater(this);
    updater.DoUpdate();
    }

     public string ApplicationName {
            get { return "MyProgram"; }
        }

        public string ApplicationID {
            get { return "MyProgramID"; }
        }

        public Assembly ApplicationAssembly {
            get { return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); }
        }

        public Icon ApplicationIcon {
            get { return this.Icon; }
        }

        public Uri UpdateXmlLocation {
            get { return new Uri("UrlToXml"); }
        }

        public Form Context {
            get { return this; }
        }
```

in my  **XML class**

```cs
    public class UpdateXml
    {
        private Version version;
        public Uri uri;
        private string fileName;
        private string md5;
        private string description;
        private string launchArgs;

        internal Version Version {
            get { return this.Version; }
        }
        internal Uri Uri {

            get { return this.Uri; }
        }
        internal string FileName {
            get { return this.fileName; }
        }
        internal string MD5 {
            get { return this.md5; }
        }
        internal string Description  {
            get { return this.description; }
        }
        internal string LaunchArgs {
            get { return this.launchArgs; }
        }
```

after a while (code running fine it come to the part that crash)

```cs
       private void DwnloadUpdate(UpdateXml update)
        {            
            updateDownloadForm form = new updateDownloadForm(update.Uri, this.applicationInfo.ApplicationIcon);
```

after this code I expect that my dl windows open  and the dl starts and the program get update

My Updater class

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace updater
{
    public class Updater
    {
        private Iupdater applicationInfo;
        private BackgroundWorker bgWorker;


        public Updater(Iupdater applicationInfo)
        {
            this.applicationInfo = applicationInfo;

            this.bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            this.bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork);
            this.bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        }

        public void DoUpdate()
        {
            if (!this.bgWorker.IsBusy)
                this.bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(this.applicationInfo);
        }
        private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Iupdater application = (Iupdater)e.Argument;

            if (!UpdateXml.ExistOnServer(application.UpdateXmlLocation))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {

                UpdateXml ux = UpdateXml.Parse(application.UpdateXmlLocation, application.ApplicationID);

                if (ux == null)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Result = ux;
                }
            }
        }
        void bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(!e.Cancelled)
            {
                UpdateXml update = (UpdateXml)e.Result;

                if(update == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Update NULL");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("test3.1");



                Console.WriteLine(this.applicationInfo.ApplicationAssembly.GetName().Version);

                if(this.applicationInfo.ApplicationAssembly.GetName().Version != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("YES!");
                } else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("NO!");
                }


                Console.WriteLine("test3.2");




                if (update != null && update.IsNewerThan(this.applicationInfo.ApplicationAssembly.GetName().Version))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("test4");
                    if (new updateInformation(applicationInfo, update).ShowDialog(this.applicationInfo.Context) == DialogResult.Yes)
                        this.DwnloadUpdate(update);
                }                
            }
        }

        private void DwnloadUpdate(UpdateXml update)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(update.Uri);
            if(update.Uri == null)
                Console.WriteLine("null");

            updateDownloadForm form = new updateDownloadForm(update.Uri, this.applicationInfo.ApplicationIcon);
            Console.WriteLine("ich bin hier drinnen");
            DialogResult result = form.ShowDialog(this.applicationInfo.Context);

            if(result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string currentPath  = this.applicationInfo.ApplicationAssembly.Location;
                string newPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(currentPath) + "\\" + update.FileName;

                UpdateApplication(form.TempFilePath, currentPath, newPath, update.LaunchArgs);

                Application.Exit();
            }
            else if(result == DialogResult.Abort)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The update download was cancelled. \nThis programm has not been modified.", "Update Download Cancelled", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There was a Problem downloading the Updat. \nThis programm has not been modified.", "Update Download Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }

        private void UpdateApplication(string tempFilePath, string currentPath, string newPath, string launchArgs)
        {
            string argument = "/C Choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 4 & Del /F /Q \"{0}\" & Choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 2 & Move /Y \"{1}\" \"{2}\" & Start \"\" /D \"{3}\" \"{4}\"{5}";
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.Arguments = string.Format(argument, currentPath, tempFilePath, newPath, Path.GetDirectoryName(newPath), Path.GetFileName(newPath), launchArgs);
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            Process.Start(info);
        }
    }
}
```

my XML Updater class

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;

namespace updater
{
    public class UpdateXml
    {
        private Version version;
        public Uri uri;
        private string fileName;
        private string md5;
        private string description;
        private string launchArgs;

        internal Version Version {
            get { return this.Version; }
        }
        internal Uri Uri {

            get { return this.Uri; }
        }
        internal string FileName {
            get { return this.fileName; }
        }
        internal string MD5 {
            get { return this.md5; }
        }
        internal string Description  {
            get { return this.description; }
        }
        internal string LaunchArgs {
            get { return this.launchArgs; }
        }
        internal UpdateXml(Version version, Uri uri, string fileName, string md5, string description, string launchArgs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("run in1");
            this.version        = version;
            this.uri            = uri;
            this.fileName       = fileName;
            this.md5            = md5;
            this.description    = description;
            this.launchArgs     = launchArgs;
            Console.WriteLine("run out 1");
        }
        internal bool IsNewerThan(Version version)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("run in 2");
            return this.version > version;
        }
        internal static bool ExistOnServer(Uri location)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("run in 3");
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(location.AbsoluteUri);
                HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                Console.WriteLine("run out 3");
                return res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
            }
            catch { return false; }
        }
        internal static UpdateXml Parse(Uri location, string appID)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("run in 4");
            Version version = null;
            string url = "", fileName = "", md5 = "", description = "", launchArgs = "";

            try
            {
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(location.AbsoluteUri);

                XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//update");

                if(node == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                version     = Version.Parse(node["version"].InnerText);
                url         = node["url"].InnerText;
                fileName    = node["fileName"].InnerText;
                md5         = node["md5"].InnerText;
                description = node["description"].InnerText;
                launchArgs  = node["launchArgs"].InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine("run out 4");
                return new UpdateXml(version, new Uri(url), fileName, md5, description, launchArgs);

            }
            catch
            {
                return null;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

My interfaces

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace updater
{
    public interface Iupdater
    {
        string ApplicationName          { get; }
        string ApplicationID            { get; }
        Assembly ApplicationAssembly    { get; }
        Icon ApplicationIcon            { get; }
        Uri UpdateXmlLocation           { get; }
        Form Context                    { get; }
    }
}
```

my  update start form where it seems to go into a loop

```cs
using System;
using updater;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace updater
{
    internal partial class updateInformation : Form
    {
        private Iupdater applicationInfo;

        private UpdateXml updateInfo;

        private UpdateInoForm updateInoForm;

        public updateInformation(Iupdater applicationInfo, UpdateXml updateInfo)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.applicationInfo = applicationInfo;
            this.updateInfo = updateInfo;

            this.Text = this.applicationInfo.ApplicationName + " - Update in Process";

            if (this.applicationInfo.ApplicationIcon != null)
                this.Icon = this.applicationInfo.ApplicationIcon;

            //this.lblNewVersion.Text = String.Format("New Version: {0}", this.updateInfo.Version.ToString());

            Timer wait = new Timer();
            wait.Interval = 5000;
            wait.Tick += new EventHandler(wait_Tick);
            wait.Start();

        }

        void wait_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;
        }

        private void Details_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.updateInfo == null)
                this.updateInoForm = new UpdateInoForm(this.applicationInfo, this.updateInfo);

            this.updateInoForm.ShowDialog(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]? Likely the problem is in code you haven't shown so the exercise to reduce your code to a minimal example can likely show you what the problem is, and if not you have at least narrowed it down substantially.

Comment: What I do when I get into loop I start adding Print statements.  Sometimes use Console.Writeline other times create a StreamWriter and use WriteLine to save debug data into a file.  You can also use log files or send to output view.

Comment: I added the needed code  till the moment it stops working

Comment: Displaying a Winforms form requires an app to call Application.Run().  Your Main() method does not use the boilerplate code for a Winfoms app, without Application.Run() the form will never display or receive any events.  A quicky workaround for the existing code is to append form.ShowDialog().  You'll encounter additional quirks, it is really rather best to start this project from the Windows Forms Application project template.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the field values, instead of the properties returning the property value. **Do not write properties like this**:

```
/// THIS PROPERTY TRIES TO RETURN ITSELF!!
internal Version Version {
  get {
    return this.Version; // you wanted to return 'this.version'
  }
}
```

You can use auto-properties like this:

```
// No more private fields
public class UpdateXml
{
  public Version Version { get; set; }
  public string FileName { get; } // Only expose a getter, can be set in the ctor
  public Uri Uri { get; set; }

  // add more properties here...

  public UpdateXml(string filename)
  {
    FileName = filename;
  }
}
```

Or learn to use a convention seen allot in C#. Prefix the private variable names:

```
public class UpdateXml
{
  private Version _version;
  private string _fileName;
  private Uri _uri;

  public Version Version => _version;
  public string FileName => _filename;
  public Uri Uri {
    get => _uri;
    set => _uri = value;
  }

  // add more properties here...

  // use the ctor to set some field values
  public UpdateXml(string filename)
  {
    _filename = filename;
  }

  // fields allow setting values later on
  public void SetLatestVersion(Version v)
  {
    if (_version == null || v > _version)
      _version = v;
  }
}
```

All in all, take care when writing code. Case does matter ;-)